# Angular *ngFor with custom indexed array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

In my component ->

```
producPrice: number[];
producPrice=new Array<number>();
for (let i=0; i<products.length; i++){
   producPrice[products[i].id]=products[i].price;
}
```

As you can see i'm inserting `products[i].price` into custom index `productPrice` array.
In my template i have to iterate over `productPrice` like this

```
<div *ngFor="let price of productPrice;let i=index;">
   <div *ngIf="price">{{price}}
   </div>
</div>
```

it works, but sometimes `products.id` is over 10000 and it takes a lot of time to iterate over these indexes. Is there a better way to iterate these kind of arrays?

Comment: For your purposes, do you want to improve the initial display time of the template or the time it takes to update the loop when the array changes?

Comment: the initial display time and update display time

Comment: You could consider to use 'infinite' scroll logic, where you load by 'packages' as required?